# Iterate over CSV rows using pandas in a faster way

Tags: python, django, pandas, django-models

I'm trying to read a CSV file through file upload from html template, and iterating over the rows and creating model object.

**views.py**

```
 ​@​login_required 
 ​def​ ​uploadStudents1​(​request​): 
 ​    ​if​ ​request​.​method​ ​==​ ​'POST'​: 
 ​        ​uploaded_file​ ​=​ ​request​.​FILES​[​'document'​] 
 ​        ​ext​ ​=​ ​os​.​path​.​splitext​(​uploaded_file​.​name​)[​-​1​].​lower​() 
 ​        ​if​ ​ext​ ​==​ ​'.csv'​: 
 ​            ​data_file​ ​=​ ​pd​.​read_csv​( 
 ​                ​uploaded_file​, ​parse_dates​=​[​'date_of_birth'​]) 
 ​            ​data_file​.​fillna​(​'-'​, ​inplace​=​True​) 
 ​            ​for​ ​_​, ​row​ ​in​ ​data_file​.​iterrows​(): 
 ​                ​Sem1Students​.​objects​.​create​( 
 ​                    ​fname​=​row​[​'first_name'​], 
 ​                    ​lname​=​row​[​'last_name'​], 
 ​                    ​reg_no​=​row​[​'reg_no'​], 
 ​                    ​gender​=​row​[​'gender'​], 
 ​                    ​birth_date​=​row​[​'date_of_birth'​], 
 ​                ) 
 ​            ​messages​.​success​(​request​, ​'Uploaded student details successfully!'​) 
 ​            ​return​ ​redirect​(​'/students'​) 
 ​        ​else​: 
 ​            ​messages​.​error​(​request​, ​"Invalid file type. Please upload again."​) 
 ​            ​return​ ​render​(​request​, ​'students/upload1.html'​) 
  
 ​    ​return​ ​render​(​request​, ​"students/upload/upload1.html"​)
```

However this process is really slow, it takes like 5-6 seconds to read and create 74 records.

Is there any better way to do this, i.e make the process faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use bulk_create because create will take time if you do it inside loop

```
 ​@​login_required 
 ​def​ ​uploadStudents1​(​request​): 
 ​    ​if​ ​request​.​method​ ​==​ ​'POST'​: 
 ​        ​uploaded_file​ ​=​ ​request​.​FILES​[​'document'​] 
 ​        ​ext​ ​=​ ​os​.​path​.​splitext​(​uploaded_file​.​name​)[​-​1​].​lower​() 
 ​        ​if​ ​ext​ ​==​ ​'.csv'​: 
 ​            ​data_file​ ​=​ ​pd​.​read_csv​( 
 ​                ​uploaded_file​, ​parse_dates​=​[​'date_of_birth'​]) 
 ​            ​data_file​.​fillna​(​'-'​, ​inplace​=​True​)
             semi_st = [] 
 ​            ​for​ ​_​, ​row​ ​in​ ​data_file​.​iterrows​(): 
 ​                ​semi_st.append(Sem1Students​​( 
 ​                    ​fname​=​row​[​'first_name'​], 
 ​                    ​lname​=​row​[​'last_name'​], 
 ​                    ​reg_no​=​row​[​'reg_no'​], 
 ​                    ​gender​=​row​[​'gender'​], 
 ​                    ​birth_date​=​row​[​'date_of_birth'​], 
 ​                ))
             Sem1Students.objects.bulk_create(semi_st)
 ​            ​messages​.​success​(​request​, ​'Uploaded student details successfully!'​) 
 ​            ​return​ ​redirect​(​'/students'​) 
 ​        ​else​: 
 ​            ​messages​.​error​(​request​, ​"Invalid file type. Please upload again."​) 
 ​            ​return​ ​render​(​request​, ​'students/upload1.html'​) 
  
 ​    ​return​ ​render​(​request​, ​"students/upload/upload1.html"​)
```